# Getting an error for a polygon using Overpy, Overpass Turbo flashes an error but I cannot see what the problem is

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I was wondering if anyone could help. I am running a Python program that has to check a couple of hundred polygons to see how many buildings they contain, 95% are polygons are processed fine and seem to be fairly accurate. 5% though fail and when I try to run these queries on Overpass turbo, an error does flash up but it's too fast to catch, I think its mentions the interpreter, and then the map appears with nothing marked. Just to add the polygons are originally GEOJSON and I transform them. One of the shorter problematic queries is below.

Can you shed any light on this?

```
[out:json][timeout:90];  
    (
      way(poly:"52.611462 -8.3355 52.611412 -8.336947 52.611919 -8.338102 52.611559 -8.338659 52.611023 -8.338279 52.610837 -8.339718 52.611468 -8.341418 52.612766 -8.342158 52.612971 -8.34081 52.61377 -8.341795 52.614628 -8.338992 52.613772 -8.338025 52.61362 -8.338395 52.613311 -8.338041 52.61343 -8.337616 52.612588 -8.336714 52.613067 -8.336277 52.612504 -8.334806 52.611951 -8.336024 52.611462 -8.3355")["building"];
      relation(poly:"52.611462 -8.3355 52.611412 -8.336947 52.611919 -8.338102 52.611559 -8.338659 52.611023 -8.338279 52.610837 -8.339718 52.611468 -8.341418 52.612766 -8.342158 52.612971 -8.34081 52.61377 -8.341795 52.614628 -8.338992 52.613772 -8.338025 52.61362 -8.338395 52.613311 -8.338041 52.61343 -8.337616 52.612588 -8.336714 52.613067 -8.336277 52.612504 -8.334806 52.611951 -8.336024 52.611462 -8.3355")["building"];
    );
    (._; >;);
    out;
```

Comment: Did you already check the error console of your browser? It will likely contain the error somewhere, even if it already disappeared from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might have seen is the usual popup in overpass turbo when it sends a query to the Overpass API backend, and waits for a reply.

However, in this case, the query is very quick to execute and also does not return any data, hence you will not see anything on the map.

[image: overpass turbo popup]

Maybe double check your query: the polygon you're referring to doesn't have any buildings in OSM. The empty result in overpass turbo is totally expected here.

[image: Nodes inside polygon]